USB Type-C Port stops working on Google Pixel 6 Pro when flashing Kernel built using official docs
Using the official docs, I built a Kernel for my Pixel 6 Pro codenamed "Raven" or "Raviole".
After flashing the Kernel, the USB Type-C port stopped working. The phone charges fine but when connecting to a computer, it doesn't prompt the gadget options such as File Transfer, Charge only etc. When connecting an OTG cable, the phone simply crashes.
I assume the correct USB kernel modules are not being compiled. I have tried different options for that in the gki_defconfig and after that, either the build fails with some DWC3 errors such as ERROR: modpost: "dwc3_otg_is_connect" [../private/google-modules/soc/gs/drivers/soc/google/exynos-pd.ko] undefined! or the issue stays there.
According to Google's documentation, we simply clone the Kernel sources, replace the ramdisk and build the kernel. However, for some reason, following these exact same steps renders my Type-C port unusable. Maybe I'm missing something or maybe the docs are incomplete.
My main goal is to enable some Kernel modules while keeping the rest stock. Please help me out if you know what I'm missing or did wrong.
Additional Info:

OS: Android 14 Build UP1A.231005.007
Kernel: Android Mainline v6.7
Branch: gs-android-gs-raviole-mainline
Docs: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-pixel-kernels

